# How can I add newItem to my list in REACT.JS?

Tags: reactjs

this is my react app, and i don't receive any error while compiling, however my new item doesn't add to my list, also the values of my array show in one line instead of showing in different lines, could you help me guys ?

I really don't know what is the problem, I wanna just add the content of text area into the list.

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const App = () => {
  const [NewTaskText, setNewTaskText] = useState('');
  const [Tasks, setTasks] = useState(['do a task', 'samira']);

  const addTask = () => {
    if (!NewTaskText) return;
    setTasks((currentTasks) => {
      return [...currentTasks, NewTaskText];
    });
    setNewTaskText('');
  };
  const onchangeInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setNewTaskText(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <form>
        <div className="row col s6">
          <div className="input-field col s10">
            <textarea
              id="textarea1"
              className="materialize-textarea"
              value={NewTaskText}
              onChange={onchangeInput}
            ></textarea>

            <label htmlFor="textarea1">What needs to be done ?</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

      <div className="row col s6">
        <br></br>
        <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="/#">
          <i className="material-icons left" onClick={addTask}>
            add_circle
          </i>
          Add
        </a>
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="row col s9">
          <ul className="collection with-header">
            <li className="collection-header">
              <h4>Todo List</h4>

              <form>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input id="search" type="search" required />
                  <label className="label-icon" htmlFor="search">
                    <i className="material-icons">search</i>Search
                  </label>
                  <i className="material-icons">close</i>
                </div>
              </form>
            </li>
            <label>
              <li className="collection-item">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <span>{Tasks.map((item) => item)}</span>

                <span>
                  <a href="#!" className="secondary-content">
                    <i className="material-icons">delete</i>
                    <i className="material-icons">check_circle</i>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </li>
            </label>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: 'setNewTaskText("");' this line is causing the issue

Comment: i have created a codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-noether-xicn5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. I've modified your code as bewlow, and you can find it in this link as well [to do task](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-pqdz5) :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const App = () => {
  const [NewTaskText, setNewTaskText] = useState('');
  const [Tasks, setTasks] = useState(['do a task', 'samira']);

  const addTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!NewTaskText) return;
    setTasks((currentTasks) => {
      return [...currentTasks, NewTaskText];
    });
    setNewTaskText('');
  };
  const onchangeInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setNewTaskText(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <form>
        <div className="row col s6">
          <div className="input-field col s10">
            <textarea
              id="textarea1"
              className="materialize-textarea"
              value={NewTaskText}
              onChange={onchangeInput}
            ></textarea>

            <label htmlFor="textarea1">What needs to be done ?</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

      <div className="row col s6">
        <br></br>
        <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="/#">
          <i className="material-icons left" onClick={(e) => addTask(e)}>
            add_circle
          </i>
          Add
        </a>
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="row col s9">
          <ul className="collection with-header">
            <li className="collection-header">
              <h4>Todo List</h4>

              <form>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input id="search" type="search" required />
                  <label className="label-icon" htmlFor="search">
                    <i className="material-icons">search</i>Search
                  </label>
                  <i className="material-icons">close</i>
                </div>
              </form>
            </li>
            <label>
              {Tasks.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                  <li className="collection-item" key = {i}>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span>{item}</span>

                    <span>
                    <a href="#!" className="secondary-content">
                    <i className="material-icons">delete</i>
                    <i className="material-icons">check_circle</i>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </li>
                )
              })}
            </label>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: i removed this part setNewTaskText(''); from my code, but it doesnt work yet, what should i do ?

Comment: thanks for your response, however it dosent work and i reiceve this erro too : vendors~main.chunk.js:29995 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `App`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3002/static/js/main.chunk.js:28:95)

Comment: Yes, I modified my answer, you can check it out.

Comment: dear saba now i dont recieve any errors, but my new item doesnt add to my todolist, without any errors, i am surprised why ? also, i just can click the check box of the first value of the array , which is "do a task" , i cannot check others checkbox

Comment: I added the link to show how the code executes. It works fine and add new tasks to the list.

Comment: hi guys, i can add newitem to my todolist properly,but i just can check the check box of the first value of my array in my list, could you help me ? how i can check the checkbox of each row in my list ?in this list it works but in reall world it doesnt,i dont know why
here is my codes :https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-water-p1r3s?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the button  inside the form to submit the form , add `e.preventDefault()`  to don't refresh the page when you add the task .

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
const App = () => {
  const [NewTaskText, setNewTaskText] = useState('')
  const [Tasks, setTasks] = useState(['do a task', 'samira'])

  const addTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!NewTaskText) return
    setTasks((currentTasks) => {
      return [...currentTasks, NewTaskText]
    })
    setNewTaskText('')
  }
  const onchangeInput = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value
    setNewTaskText(value)
  }

  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <form>
        <div className='row col s6'>
          <div className='input-field col s10'>
            <textarea
              id='textarea1'
              className='materialize-textarea'
              value={NewTaskText}
              onChange={onchangeInput}
            ></textarea>

            <label htmlFor='textarea1'>What needs to be done ?</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='row col s6'>
          <br></br>
          <button className='waves-effect waves-light btn' type="submit">
            <i className='material-icons left' onClick={addTask}>
              add_circle
            </i>
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <div className='row'>
        <div className='row col s9'>
          <ul className='collection with-header'>
            <li className='collection-header'>
              <h4>Todo List</h4>

              <form>
                <div className='input-field'>
                  <input id='search' type='search' required />
                  <label className='label-icon' htmlFor='search'>
                    <i className='material-icons'>search</i>Search
                  </label>
                  <i className='material-icons'>close</i>
                </div>
              </form>
            </li>
            <label>
              <li className='collection-item'>
                <input type='checkbox' />
                <span>{Tasks.map((item) => item)}</span>

                <span>
                  <a href='#!' className='secondary-content'>
                    <i className='material-icons'>delete</i>
                    <i className='material-icons'>check_circle</i>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </li>
            </label>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: hi guys, i can add newitem to my todolist properly,but i just can check the check box of the first value of my array in my list, could you help me ? how i can check the checkbox of each row in my list ?
here is my codes :https://codesandbox.io/s/green-voice-fu5gx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you want test if it is checked or not

Comment: look here ,I've changed your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/black-microservice-0ml7e

Comment: dear Mhammed unfortunately it doesnt work :( , actually it works in sandbox, but in my reall programm doesnt not, also i dont recieve any erros

Comment: can i see the program

Comment: it is in visual studio code, and it runs on my locall host

Comment: check now ,it's will work . https://codesandbox.io/s/black-microservice-0ml7e

Comment: yes i have , it is https://github.com/SamiraRahimi1368/react_todo

Comment: Mhammed Talhaouy it is really strange , but it doesnt work